# How to intuit 'unless'?

Tags: reasoning

I already know, and so  ask NOT about, the meanings or proofs of: A unless B = [A, except if B](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unless)
= [A if not B = Either A or B](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12241/5306).    I ask only for intuition; do NOT prove formally or use truth tables.

**My problem:** I want to avoid memorisation. So whenever I see **unless**, I always need to pause for 5 minutes to rewrite the sentence, in order to determine the meaning. This pause reveals deficiency in my knowledge, which I must resolve, because it smothers me.
So please help me dig deeper. How can this conjunction be naturalised?

Comment: It can be used in more than one way.  If you could give specific examples of uses that have confused you and required a lot of thinking on your part, that would be helpful... similarly, if you could post examples of uses of unless you understand, that too can be helpful to us.

Comment: *And all that the Lorax left here in this mess was a small pile of rocks, with one word... "UNLESS." Whatever that meant, well, I just couldn't guess. [...] "But now," says the Once-ler, "Now that you're here, the word of the Lorax seems perfectly clear. UNLESS someone like you
cares a whole awful lot, nothing is going to get better. It's not. [...]* --The Lorax by Dr. Seuss (Here is [Ben Rogge's performance on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=k25wlcFOglA#t=536))

Comment: *Unless* = "except if"

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks. Am I right that you found that definition from ODO? I included it above, but even so, how can I overcome my difficulty above?

Comment: Are you clear that "A" and "B" here are conventional notations for "A is true" and "B is true"? That is, "A unless B" means "A is [necessarily] true, except if B is true (in which case we don't know whether A is true or not)"

Answer (score 2):

*Unless* is a negated *if*.  Like *if*, it forms parts of conditional expressions.

> I will go if John goes.
>
> I will go unless John goes = I will not go if John goes.

Note that you aren't supposed to use *then* with *unless* (it's often optional with *if*), though you may hear it anyway in speech.

> If the weather is good, then we'll go to the park.
>
> Unless the weather is bad, we'll go to the park.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mnenomic that may help you remember the meaning. *Unless* is a word formed from a prepositional phrase in Middle English `of|in|on lesse than...`  It refers to a **sufficient condition**.  (The mnemonic: less <=> sufficiency).

**Don't bring the huge umbrella *unless it's pouring rain*.**

A downpour *is reason enough* to take the huge umbrella.

P.S. Per request, [sufficient](https://www.google.com/search?q=sufficient%20definition&oq=sufficient%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.4963j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please explain the mnemonic behind less <=> sufficiency? How do these 2 relate?

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think of it as:

> "I want to go to a restaurant" -> Medium priority
>
> "Unless you're feeling ill" -> High priority

Now there's a queue of things that will effect what I will do. If you're ill, that is more important than my desire to go to a restaurant. Otherwise, there's nothing stopping me from going.

This way of thinking should hopefully stop you from having to mentally go back and change A and B to be dependent on each other. You won't need to think "A is false if B is true", A is always true but will be overruled by B if B is present.