# 'except' vs 'except if' vs 'if not'

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, logic

> [1.] [[ODO:]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unless) **unless** {conjunction} = `Except if`
>   (used to introduce the case in which a statement being made is not true or valid)
>   [2.] [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075?redirectedFrom=unless)  = 2. Except, if..not:

Source: p 139, *Introduction to Logic* (2 ed, 2010) by Harry J. Gensler (see [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12238/5306) or [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/244267/50720))

> [3.] “Unless” is also equivalent to “**if not**”...

4. 1 and 3 above imply  `Except if` = **if not**.   How's this true? Can you prove this?

5. 2 and 3 above imply  `Except` =  **if not**.   How's this true? Can you prove this?

Comment: I have a bagel for breakfast every morning, *except if it's Saturday*, which is when I go to the diner. What I mean is, *if it's not Saturday* (that's the day I go to the diner), I have a bagel for breakfast. If you made a list of all the days of the week I have a bagel for breakfast, Saturday would *not* be on that list. Saturday is the *exception* to my regular bagel-breakfast rule. It it *set apart* from all the other days of the week.

Comment: This question is poorly phrased. I cannot intuit the meaning of "What's the intuition?".

Comment: @LucianSava May I ask why you deleted your answer? It looks helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

The ODO is intended to be "quick-and-dirty", foregoing nuance for brevity.

*Unless* expresses a condition which is **sufficient** to undo the clause to which the unless-clause relates.

*Except if* refers to a condition which is **necessary** to undo the clause to which the except-if-clause relates.

**We must not dip into the national fuel reserves *unless there's a fuel crisis*.**

This does not mean that we must dip into the fuel reserves during a fuel crisis; it means only that the imperative, we must not dip into the reserves, is lifted.

**We must not dip into the national fuel reserves *except if there's a fuel crisis*.**

That except-if sentence is stylistically clumsy, IMO, and it is not as clear as *unless*. Does "except if" do more than lift the imperative not to dip into the reserves? Does "except if" require us to dip into the reserves during a fuel crisis? Call in the lawyers.

I would say that neither *unless* nor *except if* requires that we dip into the fuel reserves during a fuel crisis.

**We may not dip into the fuel reserves unless there's a fuel crisis.

We may not dip into the fuel reserves except if there's a fuel crisis.**

During a fuel crisis, we may dip into the fuel reserves.

Comment: Thanks. About your 1st sentence, I quoted ODO because [this comment b user StoneyB](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56028/how-to-intuit-unless#comment105997_56028) says the same. Does this help?

Comment: No, it does not help. I don't need the help, you do. You repeatedly profess to have difficulties with certain words, yet we never see you quoting from the kind of dictionary that would actually help you to understand the nuances.

Comment: Sorry for any offense. Do you mean OED by a better dictionary? I quoted it above now.

Comment: The definition in Merriam-Webster may be better suited to your purposes. Dictionaries are the opinions of lexicographers *operating within an editorial framework*. When the definition given is a quick paraphrase or synonym, you must recognize that the lexicographer is giving only the *gist* of the meaning, not a thorough and precise definition. For most day-to-day purposes, "except, except if" would be a decent definition of *unless*; but not in a discourse on Logic.